# Convert this query to Model laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm a noob in Laravel. can anyone help me write this query in eloquent Laravel

```
select * FROM `wf_m_study_budget` a 
left join wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group b ON b.budget_id=a.budget_group 
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(regisdate, "%d-%m-%Y"))=2020
```

**example**

```
 DB::table('wf_m_study_budget')
                            ->join('wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group',
                            'wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group.budget_id', '=', 'wf_m_study_budget.budget_group')
                            ->select('wf_m_study_budget.mem_name',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.mem_id',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.mem_groupname',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.child_name',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.child_schoolname',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.child_studylevel',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.paytype',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.regisdate',
                            'wf_m_study_budget.budget_group','wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group.budget_name')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `leftjoin()` instead of `join()`,
and use `where(DB::raw(''))` to use mysql inbuilt function.

#### For Eloquent:

If you have WfMStudyBudget model:

```php
WfMStudyBudget::leftjoin('wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group b', 'b.budget_id', '=', 'wf_m_study_budget.budget_group')
              ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(regisdate, "%d-%m-%Y"))'), 2020)->select('...')
              ->get();
```

#### For QueryBuilder:

```php
DB::table('wf_m_study_budget')
    ->leftjoin('wf_m_study_ucf_budget_group AS b',
    'b.budget_id', '=', 'wf_m_study_budget.budget_group')
    ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(regisdate, "%d-%m-%Y"))'), 2020)->select('....')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @ChonnikanKunchon u'r welcome, if it helps, plz accept the answer.